# Who was the last influential sci-fi writer to die unknown?

Tags: history

H.P. Lovecraft was never popular during his lifetime and died virtually unknown in 1937. Was he the last sci-fi writer to die unknown, only to become famous in later years? If not, who was the last one?

Comment: This will depend strongly on exactly how you define "influential" and "unknown".

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Far too vague to be answered sensibly. Even the example in the question is debatable. Lovecraft was certainly *less popular* pre-death, but he wasn't an 'unknown author'. He had a wide circle of acquaintances and almost everything he wrote in his lifetime was successfully published before he died.

Comment: I want to say Ray Bradbury, as almost no one talked about his death back in 2012 : none of the movies adaptations, nothing about him on TV, and even his books weren't reedited as "integrals". But I guess it's just me being bitter as he was one of my favorite writer back then.

Comment: Bradbury was hugely popular in his own lifetime. He had bestselling books, a popular magazine with his name on the title and am anthology TV shows named after him and everything. I'm not sure how you could class him as "unknown".

Comment: An Argumetn could be made for Avrum Davidson. He was surely much less well-known adn much less popular at the time of his death than he was at the peak of his fame, perhaps 20myears before.

Answer (score 4):

Given sufficiently tenuous definitions of "unknown" and "influential", I can mention Philip K. Dick. He lived in relative poverty as a science fiction author, and died March 2nd 1982 which is before the first film adaptation of one of his novels was released. That was *Blade Runner*, on June 25th 1982.

Now clearly PKD was known and respected within the SF community, having already won the Hugo in 1963 for his 1962 novel, *The Man in the High Castle* and the John W. Campbell for *Flow My Tears, the Policeman Said*. But he was unknown *outside* that community and *posthumously influential* on American (and broader) popular culture and particularly mainstream movie culture, so I think he qualifies.

Comment: I'm not sure you could describe a bestselling author with multiple awards and dozens of published works as "unknown". Certainly he became *more recognised* posthumously but that's very far from being basically invisible to the public (in a way that, for example, Van Gogh was)

Comment: @valorum I am sure, “Given sufficiently tenuous definitions of "unknown" and "influential"” ;-)